# Having to double click hyperlinks instead of single click

Tags: hyperlink

I have a user who tells me that lately when he's been using SharePoint some of the hyperlinks he goes to click require a double click rather than a single click. I have no issue with this on my end.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the mouse configuration settings on that system; has got nothing to do with any browser nor SharePoint